# Not able to resolve my domain name on browser

Tags: macos, network, web-browser, hosts

I am using docker for application and modified the hosts file and added domain name on local browser. I added in hosts:

```
    127.0.0.1 xyz.com
```

but when I am trying to open from browser getting the following error:

```
This page isn’t working

xyz.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

What I am doing wrong?
Same application running in different OS like windows and ubuntu but here I am facing issues.

Comment: `xyz.com` or `www.xyz.com`?  - they are treated differently

Comment: actually i tried for abc.xyz.com

Comment: Just a thought but you likely don't own that particular domain (xyz.com) and if you give it a non-routable name (xyz.local) that is only available on your local network does that change anything?

Comment: actually i am trying on local machine only but still its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are modifying `/etc/hosts` in the Docker container itself, then only processes within the Docker container are going to be able to resolve that domain locally.

Thus, if you are using a browser on your Mac to access a port exposed by Docker, it knows nothing about the DNS override and will try to hit the real site -- which likely explains the message you're getting.

You need to append to your Mac's `/etc/hosts`. (You'll need sudo, a text editor, and to ensure you left the file owner, group, and permissions unchanged when you're done.)

Comment: I have already added in my Mac's /etc/hosts, but its not reflecting showing same 500 internal error